# How to sum row grand totals of corresponding fields from multiple pivot tables on different sheets?

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have multiple 3 different pivot tables on 3 different tabs. Each pivot table contains a field called "Period" (a column, thus each Period is a row). Each "Period" has multiple "Ports" (again columns). I then have the Grand Total column - which is just the sum of the "Ports" per period.

The "Period" field is dynamic, as time moves on the Periods may change and there may be 3 periods one day, 10 periods the next (i.e. 3 rows deep today, 10 rows deep tomorrow).

Every pivot table is presented in the same way. The rows in the "Period" field may be the same across all 3 worksheets. Example:

Sheet1

Period..........Grand Total

- Jan 23-27 (Grand Total = 10)
- Jan 30-03 (Grand Total = 5)

Sheet2

Period..........Grand Total

- Jan 16-20 (Grand Total = 15)
- Jan 23-27 (Grand Total = 15)
- Feb 6-10 (Grand Total = 5)

Sheet3

Period..........Grand Total

- Feb 6-10 (Grand Total = 10)

I want to output to a Range, on a 4th sheet, that shows:

Period..........Grand Total

- Jan 16-20 : 15
- Jan 23-27 : 25
- Jan 30-03 : 5
- Feb 6-10  : 15

As the totals change and the weeks change, the addition should always be done. I also want to easily add more Pivot Tables when necessary. Hope that is clear enough.

Comment: You can SUMIF() the data in the row from starting column to some arbitrary column that's outside the realm of possibilities, based on the period name.  Loop through the sheets, output on Sheet4.  Do you have any code that you've tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the below should be a base for what you're trying to do.

> Remember to enable `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` in the references.

Here we load an array with all worksheets that contain pivots. We then loop over each sheet, each pivot and then each item of the "period" field. Items of the period field that are common across the pivots are added to a dictionary.

Once we have all of the common field items, we can loop back over the dictionary and sum the row grand totals for each item, using [`GetPivotData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195919.aspx) - you may need to change the field names that are passed into this function for the code to work your end.

We then print out the item name and the grand total - and then also print the uncommon items. You can amend the code to write this data to a range.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub sum_gt_fields()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim pt As PivotTable, pt_itm As PivotItem
    Dim dictCommon As Scripting.Dictionary, dictUncommon As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim k As Variant, i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim sum_gt() As Double
    Dim pivot_sheet() As Variant

    Set dictCommon = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dictUncommon = New Scripting.Dictionary

    '' Enter all sheets that contain pivots into the array
    pivot_sheet = Array("pivot_sheet_1", _
                        "pivot_sheet_2")

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    For j = LBound(pivot_sheet, 1) To UBound(pivot_sheet, 1)
        For Each pt In wb.Sheets(pivot_sheet(j)).PivotTables
            '' May need to change "period" for actual row field name.
            For Each pt_itm In pt.PivotFields("Period").PivotItems

                '' Find out if there is the same column across pivotTables.
                If Not dictUncommon.Exists(pt_itm.Name) Then
                    dictUncommon(pt_itm.Name) = 0
                Else
                    dictUncommon.Remove pt_itm.Name
                    dictCommon(pt_itm.Name) = 0
                End If

            Next pt_itm
        Next pt
    Next j

    '' Make array the size of how many common fields were found.
    ReDim sum_gt(dictCommon.Count - 1)
    '' Iterate over common field items; sum the grand totals.
    For Each k In dictCommon.Keys
        For j = LBound(pivot_sheet, 1) To UBound(pivot_sheet, 1) '' Add to iterate over sheets that have pivots
            For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
                '' You may need to change "ports" to the pt value field name used _
                   and "period" to the row field name used.
                sum_gt(i) = sum_gt(i) + pt.GetPivotData("Ports", "Period", k)
            Next pt
        Next j
        '' Print common field names and their summed totals.
        '' You can use k and sum_gt(i) variables to output the data wherever you like.
        '' At the moment it's printing to the immediate window (open with ctrl + G)
        Debug.Print k & ": " & sum_gt(i)
        i = i + 1
    Next k

    '' Print the fields that are not common across tables.
    For Each k In dictUncommon.Keys
        Debug.Print k
    Next k
End Sub
```

To print out the unique field grand totals:

```
'' Print the fields and their grand totals, when they are unique.
Dim unique_gt() As Double
Dim gt As Double
ReDim unique_gt(dictUncommon.Count - 1)
i = 0

For Each k In dictUncommon.Keys
    For j = LBound(pivot_sheet, 1) To UBound(pivot_sheet, 1)
        For Each pt In wb.Sheets(pivot_sheet(j)).PivotTables
            On Error Resume Next
            gt = pt.GetPivotData("Ports", "Period", k)

            If Err.Number = 0 Then
                unique_gt(i) = gt
            End If

            On Error GoTo 0
        Next pt
    Next j

    Debug.Print k & ": " & unique_gt(i)
    i = i + 1
Next k
```

Comment: Useful answer but doesn't solve my issue. This is picking up my periods but not seeming to pick up the Grand Totals for each period, for each pivot table. Currently i'm returning the Period name : 0 in the  Immediate Window. Any suggestions based on this?

Comment: More help. When using GetPivotData on the "Grand Total" column, the returned strings are: "Quantity" - which is the field it is summing; "Period" followed by the Period field name.

GETPIVOTDATA("[Measures].[Quantity]",$A$5,"[Period].[Period]","[Period].[Period].&[JAN 30-03]")

Comment: Then the `sum_gt(i) = sum_gt(i) + pt.GetPivotData("Ports", "Period", k)` row should actually look like: `sum_gt(i) = sum_gt(i) + pt.GetPivotData("[Measures].[Quantity]", "[Period].[Period]‌​", k)`

Comment: Debug Output:

[Period].[Period].&[JAN 23-27]: 0
[Period].[Period].&[JAN 30-03]: 0
[Period].[Period].&[FEB 06-10]: 0
[Period].[Period].&[FEB 13-17]: 0
[Period].[Period].&[FEB 20-24]: 0
[Period].[Period].&[FEB 27-03]: 0
[Period].[Period].&[JAN 02-06]
[Period].[Period].&[JAN 09-13]
[Period].[Period].&[JAN 16-20]
[Period].[Period].&[JAN 23-27]
[Period].[Period].&[JAN 30-03]
[Period].[Period].&[FEB 06-10]

Comment: For Each pi In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("[Period].[Period]‌").PivotItems Debug.Print pi.Name Next pi

Comment: SMASHED IT BOYYYYSSSS